# Check if one element of a list is equal to a specific number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example

```
hidden_list = [63,45,76,8,59,04,13]

user_input = int(input("guess one number in the hidden list"))
```

how can i tell if the user correctly guessed one of the number in the list using if statement?

Comment: I would highly recommend you going through the tutorial. This is python 101

Answer (score 2):

```
if user_input in hidden_list:
    # tell them they won
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`in`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

```
hidden_list = [63,45,76,8,59,04,13]

user_input = int(input("guess one number in the hidden list"))

if user_input in hidden_list:
    print "You won!"
else:
    print "You lost."
```

`in` tests for membership in a collection.  In other words, the above code is testing if `user_input` is a member of `hidden_list`.

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> hidden_list = [63,45,76,8,59,04,13]
>>> user_input = int(input("guess one number in the hidden list "))
guess one number in the hidden list 63
>>> if user_input in hidden_list:
...     print "You won!"
... else:
...     print "You lost."
...
You won!
>>> user_input = int(input("guess one number in the hidden list "))
guess one number in the hidden list 100
>>> if user_input in hidden_list:
...     print "You won!"
... else:
...     print "You lost."
...
You lost.
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, what about checking if multiple elements of a list also belongs to another list?

Comment: @user2958069 - That is kinda a separate topic...but you could use `all`:  `if all(x in list1 for x in list2):`.  This checks if all of the items in `list2` can be found in `list1`.